# Render date from date field in correct timezone?

Tags: php, datetime, drupal, drupal-8

Im have a field with date time type. I see in database is always saved other timezone than my default.
When node content is rendered, date looks fine, but when i trying to get node from code i cant render date in correct timezone.

```
$node->field_customtime->getValue()
```

I have array of values with standard timezone, when i dump value, the time is wrong.
So i was trying to do it like that:

```
$value = $node->field_customtime->getValue();
$value = $value[0]['value'];
$date = new \DateTime($value);
$date = $date->getTimestamp();
echo \Drupal::service('date.formatter')->format($date);
```

And there is still raw date from database (wrong). 
I dont know how to correct display date from custom date field. I see in the form correct date (i.e. 11:00 european time) but in database is 10:00. On node page is correct 11:00 so drupal convert it somehow, but how??

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21common.inc/function/format_date/8.2.x

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you are using MySQL?
If so then unless you are saving a timestamp the timezone does not matter. It should be saved exactly how you sent it.

If it is a timestamp then the date is automatically converted into UTC for storage and then converted back into whatever timezone you have set in the mysql configuration.

> MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval. (This does not occur for other types such as DATETIME.)

What you need to check first is how you are saving the date. Are you storing a timestamp?

If not you need to check how the data is saved and see if anything is happening to the date before inserted into the database.

Unfortunately I do not know much about Drupal but after a quick google I have found out that Drupal 7 happens to have a few ways of handling the datetime. It is quite possible that this may apply for Drupal 8 and you simply need to adjust a configuration.
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3613/the-differences-between-date-time-zone-handling

Comment: Drupal store date with time as varchar :) And Drupal do the job with correct viewing timezone. Its works fine until i want to get my data from module. Just dont know what functions Drupal use to display correct date